# Sharing session data to all subdomain codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to use one `session` data for all of my subdomains.

I have created a `subdomain` in `cpanel` like this : `*.mydomain.in`

and my `*.mydomain.in` uses the same path as my `mydomain.in` example:

`mydomain.in` uses path on my server: `/public_html/mydomain.in`

`*.mydomain.in` uses path on my server: `/public_html/mydomain.in`

Now the problem is every time I visit the site it's creating a different session. For example:

I visit `mydomain.in` .... it creates a session.

I visit `example.mydomain.in` .... it creates a different session

I again visit `mydomain.in` ... it creates a different session.

my codeigniter `config` file:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'MY-SECRET-KEY-HERE';

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".mydomain.in";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
```

Any help or suggestion would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how I solved the issue.

```
 $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
 $config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
 $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
 $config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
 $config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
 $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300000000;


 $config['cookie_prefix'] = "etc_anything_";
 $config['cookie_domain'] = ".mydomain.in";
 $config['cookie_path'] = "/";
 $config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: how do i give for multiple sub domain. That is I have abc.book.com, def.book.com, pop.book.com

Comment: this works for any domain, you can try anything, ex: abc.book.com xyz.book.com both will work..

Comment: what should i give in $config['cookie_prefix'] = "mydomain_";

Comment: your domain name ex: `book_` or whatever you want... but `cookie_domain` should be your real domain name ex: `.website.com` for production...

Comment: TL;DR you only have to set `$config['cookie_domain'] = '.mydomain.com';`

Comment: These CodeIgniter settings are now outdated. Some have been deprecated. Also, the answer provides no explanation about the OP's settings and instead just offers some settings which happen to work. More explanation would make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

[Mohamed Sufian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2847436/mohammed-sufian)'s answer is largely correct, but note that as per the [Session Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=cookie_prefix#session-preferences), the `cookie_prefix` setting is ignored by the session driver.  If you want to have an instance specific cookie name you will need to edit the `sess_cookie_name` configuration option.

For example:

```php
 $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'my_prefix_ci_session';

 $config['cookie_prefix'] = "my_prefix_"; // Only relevant for non-session cookies
 $config['cookie_domain'] = ".example.com";
 $config['cookie_path'] = "/";
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions, I now use different things to easily manage all my work, and I also use `CI4` with `Django` support, furthermore, the selected answer was old and it was for `CI3`, again Thanks you have given your important time :-)

Comment: Alas, I'm still supporting a `CI3` codebase.  I wish that I weren't, but I figure there may be some unfortunate souls out there who need to know this.

Comment: I still have many projects running using `CI3` & and I still use CI3 because I know & understand that at least I'll be receiving security updates, Thanks