# How to have a common login for all the domains

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, cross-domain

i am using codeignter app on two domains abc.com and xyz.net
both have same application but on diffrent domains

i want to create a functionality that if i log in on abc.com i would automatically looged in xyz.com

given that i have same data base entrys for both tables

i need to know how to implement it and if any security breach regarding this

i have tried to search codeigniter creates entry in ci_session and creates ci_session cookie

i have tried to create a cookie for another domain but which was not possible and not advisable

also tried to use curl to create domain cookie but that was a failure too

thanks in advance

Comment: sess_use_database is not working too?

Comment: sess_use_databse is true and working but on another domain it automatically creates a new session and check on that session

Comment: i also could not pass session id as there no link between two

Comment: Its should be done with some method & share same database. Or at least provide 1 database for authentication only and separate the content database. Btw, indonesia ?

Comment: if i have same data base how to implement it

Comment: If user login from site A, then the session data was stored inside the db. On the site B, check if data was provided or not empty. IF data was True, pull the data to site B & set the login => TRUE. Then on your controller, apply the filter for check the session from database. If data exist from A the B set to allowed. Do opposite too, its hard coded, but logically its not really stress to implement. Only my 2 cents.

Comment: and second, there is cookie domain configuration. Check this both question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748422/codeigniter-sessions-across-sub-domains and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748422/codeigniter-sessions-across-sub-domains

Comment: try this [link](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Implementing-Cross-Domain-Cookies/372)

Comment: my domain names are completely different from one another

Comment: although i worked as @Nucleo1985 worked fine on the local but on the server different pcs are connecected with same ip and useragent so there is session updation of the user with another user(means that if one user logs in and another user logs in on diffrent machine first user gets the login of another user )

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is using [The HTML 5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html) using a single unique key to access it's value.

Also you can check out the stackoverflow blog post [Global Network Auto Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) for more details.

Comment: still i store a codeigniter library automatically stores sess-id in data base and if it is not match with the cookie in browser it wont let me login