# How to configure CodeIgniter and Ion Auth with front and back ends into different domains

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, session-cookies, ion-auth

I'm working on a modernization of and old CodeIgniter Application. By separateing the application in front and back ends.

The new Front end is an angular SPA application. The backend still uses a of CI application. The CI uses Ion_Auth to authorize users.

Everything works fine if both are into the same domain, for instance `localhost`

The problem is that each part must be on **different url domains**, ie.:

- Frontend - localhost:8081, in the future will be example.com
- Backend - localhost:8082, in the future will be api.example.com

This way Ion Auth is able to log-in users, but when I query if user is logged in, it returns `false`. The CI doesent holds the session anymore.

I also noted that when both are into the **same domain** the `session` folder only contains only one file, which means that CI recognizes the session.

When I set it onto **different domains**, the `session` folder creates a new file for each XHR Request. That means that CI is not holding session anymore.

Why this is happening? What Should I do to make front and backend to work properly with Ion Auth?

Here are my CI configuration:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'var/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

I also set :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

And this is how I'm making the XHR requests.

```
$http({
  url: $rootScope.API_URL + "/user/check",
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": undefined },
  data: { /*...*/ }
}).then( /*...*/ )
```

Comment: both frontend and backend use CI as the server-side php framework? "the session folder creates a new file for each XHR Request." - for every single request a new session file is created? either way, CI uses cookies to identify sessions, your domain is probably of issue here. as long as the session files are stored on the same server you should be able to get it to work after some trial and error. might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748422/codeigniter-sessions-across-sub-domains

Comment: both frontend and backend use CI as the server-side php framework? Only Backend. Front is pure HTML + JS.

For every single request a new session file is created?  YES  every one

Comment: have you looked at the link?

Comment: it dont solve my priblem @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#section_5

> The most interesting capability exposed by both [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and CORS is the ability to make "credentialed" requests that are aware of HTTP [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and HTTP Authentication information. By default, in cross-site `XMLHttpRequest`" or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) invocations, browsers will **not** send credentials. A specific flag has to be set on the `XMLHttpRequest`" object or the `Request` constructor when it is invoked.

(Special Highlight to the NOT keyword in the sentence).

I other words. It will no work anyway. A special flag must be present in the XHR request. When using AngularJS `$hhtp` object I must use `withCredentials: true`

```
$http({
  url: ...
  withCredentials: true
})
```

Also need to set both headers in API responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
```

Unfortunately I was not able to use`*` as  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, instead I must use the correct domains.

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

This way I was able to make Cross origin XHR Requests with cookies preserving sessions.