# How can i share CodeIgniter Session across two different CI CodeBase?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have two CI Code base say projectX and projectY (Two Different Code Base and yes CI systems files are also separate but same version), Where ProjectX is the main site say http://projectx.com and ProjectY is http://projecty.projectx.com

Now when a user logs into the system (ProjectX) and clicks on some link that takes him to ProjectY. I want the user gets logged into SystemY with same session that was activated when he/she had logged into SystemX.

So my question is it possible and if yes then how or if 'NO' then what are possible ways to accomplish this as i don't want to show one more popup for login

Comment: [I think this is what you are looking for][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588700/sharing-session-data-to-all-subdomain-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks @LuckyBurger for the above link i will definitely give it a try, but one thing i am not sure will i have to change the config.php session array varible in both my code base as i have two code base and hence two config.php file, well i will let you know i will give a try with all possible available ways

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all thanks to @LuckyBurger for the link he has given in comment and yes that is a perfect solution for the problem all you have to do is to change the config file in both the code base with same values for session config array